# dropdownDialog widget cant listen to dialogopen

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, jquery, magento-2.1.9

I wanted to add some custom animations to my minicart and therefore I have to listen for [`dialogopen`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open) and [`dialogclose`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close) events.

The script is loaded and executed but all my attached listeners are not triggered and I cant get it to work.
I wrote an example trying multiple approaches but none of them seem to work.

JS:

```
define(["jquery", "jquery/ui"], function($) {

    console.log("test");

    $("[data-block='minicart']").on("dialogopen", function(e) {
        console.log("dialogopen");
    });

    $(".ui-dialog-minicart").on("dialogopen", function(e) {
        console.log("dialogopen 1");
    });

    $("body").on("dialogopen", "*", function(e) {
        console.log("dialogopen 2");
    });


    $("[data-block='minicart']").on("open", function(e) {
        console.log("open");
    });

    $(".ui-dialog-minicart").on("open", function(e) {
        console.log("open 1");
    });

    $("body").on("open", "*", function(e) {
        console.log("open 2");
    });

    return;
});
```

Does the Magento UI library intercept these events or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok,
after some more research I found the solution.
The events are prefixed with `dropdown`.

So to attach the handler call:

```
$("[data-block='minicart'].on("dropdowndialogopen", (e) => {});
```